# Why doesn't this program echo any string?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Context- I'm in the process of sorting out, backing up, and archiving a load of my grandmother's pictures.  I've just come across a set of folders where all of the file extensions have some junk numbers at the end *`(100_105.jpg_25_1025, 100_106.jpg_26_1026, ...)`*
I'm trying to make a batch program that will identify the file name parts, delimited by the period `(".")`, and then remove from the second part any junk part which will be defined as the underscore `("_")` and anything after it.
BUT, I've hit an obstacle early on.  I can't get the program to spit out the second part of the file name.
Here's what I've got going on...

```
for %%G in (*.jpg*) do (
for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%a in (%%G) do echo %%b)
```

There aren't any errors.  There's absolutely no output. My echos look like this...

```
G:\Project>(for /F "tokens=* delims=." %a in (100_0661.jpg_25_1026) do echo %b
```

If I replace `(%%G)` with `(100_0661.jpg_25_1026)`, then it gives the expected output of "`jpg_25_1026`".

What's wrong with this?  Is there a better solution to this problem?  I know almost no programming lingo so go easy on me please.

Comment: Can you use a proper scripting language such as python, php, javascript or even vbscript?  It would be much easier

Comment: No.  I have a basic understanding of python, but don't know how to actually write/compile/run the programs.  Online resources don't like their "absolute beginner's guide" to include accessing environments or how to handle whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you don't need to script a whole program for that. Try:

```
rename *.jpg* *.jpg
```

Given your example filenames, `100_105.jpg_25_1025` and `100_106.jpg_26_1026`, you'll end up with `100_105.jpg` and `100_106.jpg`.

This kind of wildcard replacement has been an often-overlooked feature of `rename` since the DOS days...

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%G in (*.jpg) do (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ("%%G") do echo %%b
)
```

Set %%G in quotes process it as a string.Otherwise with will try to read the %%G as text file.

But there's easier way to rename pictures.Save this as bat in the same directory as the pictures (%%~nG will expand the picture to its name without the extension):

```
@echo off

    for %%G in (*.jpg_*_*) do (
        ren "%%~nxG"  "%%~nG.jpg" 
    )
```

It will not search in sub-directories though.And will process only the files that apply the mask `*.jpg_*_*` . Its possible to process also sub-folders but its not mentioned in the question .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a gui freeware utility called [Rename Master](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/) .  It can do what you want and much more, and it provides a preview of what the result will be before running it.